# Access ftp server from Google Cloud Engine VM

Tags: ftp, google-compute-engine

I have created a LAMP Bitnami VM on Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine.

`vsftpd` is installed already and I have edited the options to include:

```
listen=YES
listen_address=0.0.0.0
write_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_umask=022
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.allowed_users
```

I have the PHP server up and running on `http://my-ip-address` but when I try to navigate to `ftp://my-ip-address` the browser just hangs.

I haven't used ftp for about 100 years so I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way.

Do I need to do something with the firewall? I tried to do that but GCP wouldn't accept ftp as a protocol.

I've also tried with Filezilla but I get 'connection timed out'.

What am I missing please?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here - Though I'm pretty sure there are dozens of questions like this already. - Also, why FTP? Use SFTP!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have GCP firewall rule (ingress) in place to allow `tcp:21` for FTP traffic to reach to the instance.

You can install **tcpdump** package on the server to monitor the traffic for verification.

To monitor the traffic on port 21 (ftp) can use the following syntax:

```
sudo tcpdump -i interface port 21
```

Example: `sudo tcpdump -i eth0 port 21`

I verified this on the GCE LAMP Bitnami VM with vsftpd package installed and was able to ftp from browser.

Moreover, FTP is an insecure protocol. You can set-up SFTP for more security and encrypted traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you missing Google Cloud Firewall, You have open some ports to make a successful connection with your ftp server. Go and visit this [Set up an FTP Server on Google Cloud Platform -siteyaar.com](https://www.siteyaar.com/setup-ftp-server-on-google-cloud/) blog post, This will help you.

First add this line in vsftpd.conf file.

```
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
```

After that open this ports 20,21,990,40000-50000 from Google cloud Firewall.